# Add cookie to response with OkHttp3 / Retrofit

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to add a header to HTTP responses. This is my Interceptor which is not working:

```
builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        Request addedTestRequest = request.newBuilder().addHeader("TEST", "test").build();

        Response response = chain.proceed(addedTestRequest);

        final Response addedTestResponse = response.newBuilder().addHeader("TEST", "test").build();

        return addedTestResponse;
    }
});
```

I can see the header TEST in outgoing traffic (requests) but **not in incoming traffic (responses)**. Do you know what is the problem or is there another way to add headers to responses?

Note: I am using [franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar](https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar) with OkHttp3 / Retrofit, if that influences anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you’re logging the response before your additional headers are added. If you reorder the interceptors you’ll most likely see the response header where you expect it, but you’ll lose the request header.

Looking at [this overview](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) might help you to understand which interceptors see which values.

Comment: Thats very clever. The code was working, logging Interceptor just got the old data

Answer (score 0):

The request headers and response headers are different. I'm not familiar with that cookie store but this test explain how to use cookies in okHtttp.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/c581f5ddc6a091e36e745a44ca787d903e32df51/okhttp-tests/src/test/java/okhttp3/CookiesTest.java#L78

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add two interceptors into your OkHttp instance, which will do next operations:

- scan cookies from the responses;
- save found cookies into the prefs;
- attach cookies from the prefs into the requests;

Of course, you can customize this logic according to your tasks.

```
public class AddCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
        HashSet<String> preferences = (HashSet) Preferences.getDefaultPreferences().getStringSet(Preferences.PREF_COOKIES, new HashSet<>());
        for (String cookie : preferences) {
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
        }

        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        if (!originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
            HashSet<String> cookies = new HashSet<>();

            for (String header : originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
              cookies.add(header);
            }

            Preferences.getDefaultPreferences().edit()
                    .putStringSet(Preferences.PREF_COOKIES, cookies)
                    .apply();
        }

        return originalResponse;
    }
}
```

---

```
 OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
 okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new AddCookiesInterceptor());
 okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor());
```